# jQuery-Add new elements after user specifies the quantity

Tags: javascript, jquery

User specifies the quantity of new element (div) to be created and clicks on a button to create the number of elements. The `Javascript` code is working but I want to use `jQuery`. Help please!

HTML

```
Quantity of div: <input type="text" id="quantity" name="quantity" value=""><br /><br />
<button id="create" onclick="addFields()>Create</button>
        <div id="container">
        </div>
```

Javascript

```
function addFields() {
    var number = document.getElementById("quantity").value;
    var container = document.getElementById("container");
    while (container.hasChildNodes()) {
        container.removeChild(container.lastChild);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < number; i++) {
        container.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Div "+(i + 1)));    
    }
}
```

How do I do it in `jQuery`? Thanks very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to let a user specify the number of divs to append to your container div using jQuery:

```js
$('#create').click(function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < $('#quantity').val(); i++) {
    $('#container').append('<div>Div '+i+'</div>');
  }
})
```

```css
#container > div {
border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Quantity of div: <input type="text" id="quantity" name="quantity" value=""><br /><br />
<button id="create">Create</button>
<div id="container"> </div>
```

The CSS is there to visualize the new divs. First you create a click handler and bind it to the button. Then when the button is clicked, it takes the value from the input and uses that to create a loop to append divs to your container.